# Multiple partial classes with a single namespace returning error

Tags: c#, .net, partial-classes

I've declared a partial class with name "BusinessLayer" in BL namespace, but now I want to add another class with same name, and with keyword "partial" in that namespace. But Whenever I try to add class with with name "BusinessLayer", I'm getting an error, saying I can't declared multiple classes with same name in a namespace. Then how can I use partial classes in a single namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would fix your code if you'd write some, even just as an example.

Anyway, you should **tag both as "partial".**
Any declaration of this class, anywhere, should have the "partial" keyword in order to allow it to compile properly.

Answer (score 0):

All declarations of the class must have the partial keyword, otherwise they will be interpreted as different classes and being in the same namespace will cause a compile time error.

My best guess is you're missing a partial keyword somewhere.

Edit: By the way, partial classes can only be declared in the same assembly, iirc. So all parts of the partial class need to be in the same assembly.